# How to get the 1st and 3rd quartile of a list of sorted numbers without modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, statistics

So I want to find the 1st quartile and 3rd quartile for a list like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

---

but I can't use any modules outside other than `math`, and nope, I can't use `numpy`, as this is program is for my calculator's **micro-python**, which doesn't allow importing of external modules, so I'm trying to find a way to do it with pure python only, i've already found a way to get the median, and the 1st quartile, but improvements are welcome.

```py
    # lower quartile
    if number_of_data % 2 == 0:
        median1 = sorted_listed_data[number_of_data//4] 
        median2 = sorted_listed_data[number_of_data//4 - 1] 
        median = round((median1 + median2)/2, 5)
    else:
        median = round(sorted_listed_data[number_of_data//4], 5)


    # median
    if number_of_data % 2 == 0:
        median1 = sorted_listed_data[number_of_data//2] 
        median2 = sorted_listed_data[number_of_data//2 - 1] 
        median = round((median1 + median2)/2, 5)
    else:
        median = round(sorted_listed_data[number_of_data//2], 5)
```

Comment: Instead of dividing by 2 or by 4, you could multiply by some decimal value (.25 or .5 here) and round down (converting to `int` does this naturally), and generalize the code that way. (The condition is not really whether there are an even or odd number of elements in the list, but whether we pick an exact integer with our index calculation. Also, you may consider using a weighted average; `number_of_data / 4` (note single `/`) could be `.25` or `.75`, which might suggest biasing the result.

Comment: that doesn't give the right answers for some reason, and you'd have to add the float() function in addition to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These allow finding the 1st quartile, median, and 3rd quartile in python for a list like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, if the list is unsorted then sort it using `list.sort()`

```py
def find_median(List): # finds the median of a sorted_list
    number_of_data = len(List)
    if number_of_data % 2 == 0:
        median = (List[(number_of_data//2)]+List[(number_of_data//2-1)])/2
    else:
        median = List[(number_of_data//2)]
    return median

middle = len(sorted_listed_data)//2

# lower quartile
lower_quartile = find_median(sorted_listed_data[:middle])

# median
median = find_median(sorted_listed_data)

# upper quartile
upper_quartile = find_median(sorted_listed_data[middle:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def quartile(my_list): #Avoid using recursive function to save memory
    length = len(my_list)  #using copies of long data list
    start = (length)//2
    if length%2:
        start = start
        end = start + 1
        median = sum(my_list[start:end]) # sum single element list as value
    else:
        start = start - 1
        end = start + 2
        median = sum(my_list[start:end]) / 2.  # Average middle two elements
    #Compute Quatrile 1
    q1start = start//2
    flag = False
    if start%2:
        q1start = q1start
        q1end = q1start + 1
        q1 = sum(my_list[q1start:q1end]) # a single element
    else:
        flag = True
        q1start = q1start - 1
        q1end = q1start + 2
        q1 = sum(my_list[q1start:q1end]) / 2. # Average middle two elements
    #Compute Quartile 3
    q3start = end + q1start
    q3end = end + q1end
    if flag:
        q3 = sum(my_list[q3start:q3end]) / 2.
    else:
        q3 = sum(my_list[q3start:q3end])
    return q1, median, q3

odd_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,  8,  9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
odd_list2 = [1,3,6,9,12,15,17.5,18,  20.4,  25,28,31,35,38,41,44,48]
even_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,  7,8,  9,10,11,12,13,14]
even_list2 =  [1,2,4.4,6,  8.5,  10,11,12,14, 16,17,18,18.5,19,20,21,22,25,28,30]
```

neg_list = [-12,-11.5,-10,-8,-7.5,  -6,-5.5,   -4,-1.2,-1,-0.5,-0.4]

```
print(quartile(odd_list))
print(quartile(odd_list2))
print(quartile(even_list))
print(quartile(even_list2))
print(quartile(neg_list))
```

Comment: I will resubmit after I look at it again. I see some errors in my code.

Comment: This is my updated code. It uses pointers to q1, median, and q3. I tested it on lists of various lengths, non-consecutive numbers, negative numbers. It does not care whether data length is even or odd. I like MahdeenSkyYT's method for its simplicity but it requires copying data to new lists which takes more memory if you have very long data length.

Comment: A word of caution: Be sure to test with non-consecutive numbers, and include floating point numbers in your tests, too.